# What kind of HTTP requests can be pending after the load event has fired?

Tags: javascript, http, dom, dom-events

I was under the impression the `load` event indicated a page had finished loading -- meaning all the HTTP requests for the page and its dependencies had completed, but a quick look in my Network tab tells me I am missing something. On the specific page I am working on, there are still several pending HTTP requests after this event has fired, many of which are pertinent to the page and, to my expectation, should be triggered (dependent?) on the original request but apparently aren't.

Can someone help me understand what `load` considers a dependency on the page and why I might be seeing so much HTTP activity after the `load` event has fired?

Comment: Maybe it's sending AJAX requests?

Comment: What items are still pending?

Comment: It only fires when whatever is in original source is loaded...but doesn't wait or even know about script related content requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load` event doesn't wait for any content requested in your javascript.

It waits only for the content requested in you HTML.

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

**Conclusion** : If you are requesting any content in your script, like image, json data, etc . load event will not wait for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the onload event, it occurs when an object has been loaded.

> **onload** is most often used within the  element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including
>   images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp